# c programming- calculation of maximum distance between two different points

Tags: c

firstly, i write this code:

```
int X, Y;
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    printf("Enter X and Y: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &X, &Y);
}

int A[X][Y];

for (int i=0;i<X;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<Y;j++){
        printf("A[i][j]:");
        scanf("%d", &A[i][j]);
    }
}
```

but, I have trouble with the calculation I couldn't improve it.

Comment: What part of that are you having trouble with? What do you have so far?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: How can you write the program? A) describe the algorithm abstractly. B) think about a suitable data structure for the collection of points. C) Implement in C.

Comment: Just a few sidenotes: `int A[X][Y];` is not possible in standard C, it's a gcc extension. Second, when you read the numbers, you should scanf `A[i][j]` and not `A[X][Y]`. Also when you read numbers, in your printf, you don't need a `%d` because you are not printing anything besides the text `"A[X][Y]: %d\n"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you appear to be looking for is the [furthest neighbour](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2322992) between points.  Writing a brute force solution is trivial, just compare distances between every possible pair of points.  As per the link, far better solutions exist.

**Edit:**  Distance between two points is

```
double distance(double x1,double y1,double x2, double y2)
{
  return sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tips:

- Every point needs more than a variable, so you have to use a _ _ _ _ _ _ (write here your answer)
- The distance between two points can be computed via the Pythagorean theorem
- You have to compare every point's distance against every other point's distance